# How to get Firebase storage URL

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am sending FCM notifications with image links from my backend written in Go. The images are stored in Firebase-storage. I need to resolve the bucket path into a Url that I can use to create the FCM notification.

There seems to be a Javascript function (getDownloadUrl) to do this. How do I get the download URL in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDownloadUrl` is a feature of Firebase client SDKs that read and write Cloud Storage.  There is no direct equivalent for backend and server SDKs.

Cloud Storage has a similar concept called [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) that you can use to create URLs that directly access content in Cloud Storage.  You can use the REST APIs directly as shown in the documentation, or if you're using the Go SDK, you can simply call [SignedURL](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#SignedURL) directly to get a URL that meets your specifications.

Comment: Does this solution mean that I have to get a signedURL for every single file that my server needs?
I am returning html from server and need image src attrs with links to firebase cloud storage files. 

The ideal solution is to store the download url in the database instead of storing the ref, and getting download urls for hundreds of files on each page request.

Is that not possible with the Go Admin SDK?